# Javascript Hangman Game Running Functions += Times After Reset

Tags: javascript

Ok this is my very first ever coding project. I'm self taught and thought creating a hangman game my 2 young kiddos could enjoy would be fun.
I have the game coded and it runs perfectly fine the first time through however, once I click on my reset button to restart the game, my lives start going down by 2 instead of one. After a third reset it goes down by three, and so on. Any console.log()s I put in to check run as many times as well.
I've spend hours racking my brain trying to figure it out and I've looked all over and I'm just not getting what's wrong. I thought about just saying screw it and resort to refreshing the page after every play through to avoid the problem but my brain wont let me do that.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the problem? I know my code is probably not the most efficient and can definitely use to touch ups, but like I said, this is my first ever project and I know efficiency and skill will come with time and practice (like this). Below is the main chunk of my code.

```
function gameStart() {
    // user writes in a word
    pickedWord = prompt('pick a word').toUpperCase();
    pickLetterHeading.innerText = 'Pick a Letter'
    numLivesSec.hidden = false;
    startBtn.disabled = true;
    gameIsGoing = true;
    resetBtn.disabled = false;
    // enables buttons to press
    for (let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('letterBtnClass')[j].disabled = false;
    }
    numLives = 7;
    numLivesRemaining.innerText = numLives;
    // calls the main game function
    gameInProgress();
}

function reset() {
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    pickedWord = '';
    gameIsGoing = false;
    resetBtn.disabled = true;
    pickLetterHeading.hidden = true;
    numLivesSec.hidden = true;
    while (guessedSec.firstChild) {
        guessedSec.removeChild(guessedSec.firstChild);
    }
    for (let l = 0; l < alphabet.length; l++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('letterBtnClass')[l].disabled = true;
        letters[l].classList.replace('correct', 'letterBtnClass');
        letters[l].classList.replace('incorrect', 'letterBtnClass');
    }
    numLives = 7;
}

function gameInProgress() {
    pickLetterHeading.hidden = false;
    wordInProgress = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < pickedWord.length; i++) {
        let lettersToGuess = document.createElement('span');
        lettersToGuess.innerText = '_';
        guessedSec.appendChild(lettersToGuess);
        wordInProgress += '_';
    }

    for (let btn = 0; btn < letters.length; btn++) {
        letters[btn].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            letters[btn].disabled = true;

            if (pickedWord.indexOf(letters[btn].innerText) == -1) {
                console.log('letter not there!');
                numLives -= 1;
                numLivesRemaining.innerText = numLives;
                console.log('TESTING!')

                // checks if you have any tries left. If you have 0, then runs game over
                if (numLives == 0) {
                    console.log('GAME OVER!')
                    gameIsGoing = false;
                    pickLetterHeading.innerText = 'You lose. Try again.'
                    for (let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('letterBtnClass')[j].disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // checks if the letter picked matches anything in the chosen word
            for (let x = 0; x < pickedWord.length; x++) {
                if (letters[btn].innerText == pickedWord[x]) {
                    // adds class to chosen letter to show you guess correctly
                    letters[btn].classList.add('correct');
                    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[x].innerText = pickedWord[x];
                    wordInProgress[x] = pickedWord[x];

                    // if picked letter matches something in the chosen word, changes the "_" to the correct letter to show user progress
                    String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, char) {
                        let a = this.split("");
                        a[index] = char;
                        return a.join("");
                    }
                    wordInProgress = wordInProgress.replaceAt(x, pickedWord[x]);

                    // when the word is complete. will show you win
                    if (wordInProgress == pickedWord) {
                        console.log("WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!");
                        pickLetterHeading.innerText = 'YOU WIN!'
                        for (let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                            document.getElementsByClassName('letterBtnClass')[j].disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // since you chose incorrectly it adds a class to the button to show a bad choice
                    letters[btn].classList.add('incorrect');
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Put another debug statement in to check if `gameInProgress()` is called on every reset. If that's the case, you end up adding multiple click listeners to every letter button.

Comment: It doesn't look like you removed the event listener in `reset()`

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me an example of how to do that?